# How would I compare two fields in an SQL SELECT statement to then select other fields based on this result?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I have a table which contains a list of products for a company. They input data about how much stock they have and also the level at which they want to be reminded that they need to order new stock.

For example:

```
    +-------+-------+----------------+
    |column1|column2|column1<=column2|
    +-------+-------+----------------+
    |value1 |value1 |   true         |
    |value2 |value3 |   false        |
    |value4 |value4 |   true         |
    +-------+-------+----------------+
```

I want to list all the true results in a form which the user is then able to navigate through. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about 
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1<=column2` ?

Comment: The statement I tried was:

`SELECT PartID,PartName,PartStockLevel,MakeName,ModelName FROM tblParts WHERE PartStockLevel <= StockWarnLevel;`

and that didn't return any values as it created an error whenever I attempted to read the dataset. I've probably missed something out that's really obvious but I can't see it. There is data that it should be fetching, though.

Comment: Everything is spelled correctly, PartStockLevel and Stockwarnlevel have the same type and are part of the dataset obviously?
Try SELECT * instead of the fieldnames...
Does: SELECT * FROM tblParts; return anything?

Comment: The error was [this](http://bit.ly/IfvE4d). I found out that the problem was due to the fact that one of the fields was text as I assumed that it would need to be as I was using a - sign. Turns out I was wrong and now it works like a charm - thanks to everyone and I'm sorry it was a silly mistake :P

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL I would suggest a statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 <= column2
```

Comment: As with the answer above, I tried this and well, the reply above gives full details - thanks for the very quick response though!